# Details About Glide Library

Tags: android, image, resize, compression, android-glide

I am using the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library and wanted to know some more details about it.Does it load the entire picture into the memory,for example if i have a 1920x1080 picture and load it onto a phone with a screen size of 640x480 does it resize and compress or load the whole thing?

Also the thumbnail feature of glide,does it just load a icon version of the image so that it can be used for something like an avatar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Depending on selected diskCacheStrategy Glide saves or original image (1920x1080 in your case) or image processed separately for each of your views (for example with .override(int width, int height) method).  The only optimisation which Glide makes for you is storing of image in RGB_565 format instead of system default ARGB_8888.

If you are looking for strategy to reduce trafic as well as memory consumption here is description of model with downloading of images with custom sizes:

[backend requirements](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/IMAGES.md)

[android client implementation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Downloading-custom-sizes-with-Glide)

2) Thumbnail feature - it is just an option to fill the container view with reduced copy of original image insted of showing empty container or 'progress view' while downloading final image. Here is description of it's rule from Java doc thumbnail(float f):

```
* Loads a resource in an identical manner to this request except with the dimensions of the target multiplied
* by the given size multiplier. If the thumbnail load completes before the fullsize load, the thumbnail will
* be shown. If the thumbnail load completes afer the fullsize load, the thumbnail will not be shown.
```

So it is not the proper vay for avatar styling. The usual way instead is combination of override and centerCrop options.

Comment: I was using glide to just load an image from the gallery and display it in an image view in the app,using the override didnt seem to make much of a differenc,so should i just use inSampleSize to scale the image and then display that manually or can glide do this scaling for me or is there any other library that handles this?

Comment: Yes, in this case you can use inSampleSize and change the view appearance by modifying of android:scaleType parameter. Glide in this way will be used only as an easy and safe tool for loading the image.

Comment: thought so too,i will keep the question open for a little while longer in case there are other opinions if not i will mark your's as the correct one.